# Gaussian Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

Does a "Gaussian Matrix" refer to a matrix that has undergone gaussian elimination to become an upper triangular matrix (the *U* in lu factorization), or instead to the elimination matrix that multiplies a matrix to make it upper triangular via elimination steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I never heard of a *Gaussian matrix* in the context of Gaussian/Gauss-Jordan elimination. Rather, the matrices were referred to directly by their property. For example - as you mentioned - *upper triangular* matrix. The term does not pop up on [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) either. Even in this [thesis](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/SankarThesis.pdf) the term only arises for realizations of Gaussian random variables organized to a matrix; no direct relation to the elimination procedure.

However, I know *Gaussian matrices* from a very different context. Namely, as the Gram matrix when a Gaussian kernel is applied. This seems to be somewhat backed by [WolframAlpha](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GaussianMatrix.html).